# How to use filter result with list integer in IQueryable

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

My program contains several tables. Some of these tables are as follows:
Country table - Product table - ProductCountry (junction table).
When filters are applied on the page of the store (example.com/shop), I want to apply the filter of the selected countries to the result, which goes through various stages (the ID of these countries is a list of integer)
I wrote several ways, all of which have errors.
Thank you for your help

```
IQueryable<ProductLocalization> result = _context.ProductLocalizations
                .Include(c => c.Languages)
                .Include(c => c.ProductPropertyLocalizations)
                .Include(c => c.Product)
                .Include(c => c.Product.UserProducts)
                .Include(c => c.Product.Brand)
                .Include(c => c.Product.Category)
                .Include(c => c.Product.Category.CategoryPropertyLocalizations)
                .Where(c => c.LanguageId == languageId);

if (countryId.Count != 0)
            {
                result = result.Where(c => countryId.Contains(c.Product.CountryProducts.Select(b => b.CountryId));
                result = result.Where(c => c.Product.CountryProducts.Any(b => b.CountryId == countryId));
                result = result.Where(c => countryId.Any(b => b == c.Product.CountryProducts[0].CountryId)); //for example
                result = result.Where(c => c.Product.CountryProducts.Select(c => countryId.Any(c.CountryId)));
                result = result.Where(c => c.Product.CountryProducts.FindAll(b => b.CountryId == countryId));
                result = result.Where(c => c.Product.CountryProducts.Select(c => c.CountryId).Contains(countryId);
                result = result.Where(c => countryId.Any(b => b == c.Product.CountryProducts.Select(a=>a.CountryId)));
            }
```

Comment: Would be great to get some sample data (2-3 rows) and the expected output. It should also contain the problematic values that leads to the undesired outcome.

Comment: in row2 : operator '==' cannot applied if type int and list<int> , in row 3: For example, I used index 0.
Is not there a solution?

Comment: We need your table classes, for each table 2-3 entries and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following filter:

```cs
result = result.Where(c => 
   c.Product.CountryProducts.Any(b => countryId.Contains(b.CountryId))
);
```